# Send Facebook invitations only to people who are not registred on my website

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

For my current project I'm building a Laravel project where each customer will manage his company online. Each customer will invite his users to join his company on the platform, and we will use existing social networks for that, and especially Facebook. But I'm struggling with that invitation system.

Each customers will have to link their business page online with the Fabook Graph API with a page access token I'll stock on database. Like this  customers will be able to send invitations through Facebook from our platform.

The problem is that I would let them invite only people who are following them on Facebook and are not on our platform. I saw that it was not possible from the Facebook GRAPH API to get the list of users who liked a Business page. It's only possible from the user to know if he like a specific page if he gave the authorization.

I would like to know how could I reach that goal ? Indeed, I would like to avoid people who are already on our website to be spammed on customers Facebook pages. Would it be a good idea to create a Facebook App linked to our Laravel platform to have more possibilites here on check in system ?

Comment: It's not about spamming people. In the end, we will need their authorization on the platform to link their Facebook profile to it. So they are in charge in the end, and we will be transparant. The goal is to avoid them to be spammed more than necessary. If they are on our platform, useless for them to see a post to join us on our website. I have to say that they will be rewarded to come on our platform by our customers. So in the end it's not about us, but what customer will do with their own social networks and followers. We just want to offer the best options for followers to avoid that.

Comment: How to invite people to your app using Facebook is explained at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#faq_104376946653191

Comment: The problem of this method is that it implies that each customers need to use the app and do everything from there + connect the app to our existing platform. Usefull to invite people on board, but won't change the problem that if they share an invite on their wall, going to spam all the followers.

Comment: Unfortunately it is the only method.